# Почему не срабатывает проверка через in в javaScript?

Tags: javascript

Есть объект с пустым ключом и значением ("": ""). Хочу проверить, есть ли пустой ключ или значение в объекте (пустые они должны быть не всегда, для этого и проверка) через
`if ("" in Object.keys(languagesValues) || "" in Object.values(languagesValues))`. Но хотя я знаю, что в объекте есть пустой и ключ, и значение, все время возвращается false, будто ничего такого там нет. Почему так?

Comment: Потому что вы видимо не понимаете [что делает in](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

Comment: `if (Object.keys(languagesValues).includes('') || Object.values(languagesValues).includes(''))` - используйте метод массива [includes](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#indexof-lastindexof-i-includes). Или так `if (languagesValues[''] === '')`